# ReactJS creating a loop in render

Tags: reactjs

**Use case/Situation:**

I created an app with jwt-token login, which works fine. As soon as the user is logged in, he has access to see a table with cocktails whose content comes from a RestAPI.

Works so far so good, but react creates a loop and rerenders the `render()` every second.

```
// ... imports
import { getCocktails } from '../../actions/cocktailActions';

class ListCocktailPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cocktails: [],
            errors: {},
            isLoading: true
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { getCocktails } = this.props;

        console.log('This string is logged every second');

        // calling function from cocktailActions
        this.props.getCocktails().then((response) => {
            this.setState({ cocktails: response.data.data, isLoading: false });
        });

        const cocktailsContent = (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                        <th>Modified</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.cocktails.map(function(item, key) {
                        return(
                            <tr key={key}>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{item.attributes.name}</td>
                                <td>{item.attributes.description}</td>
                                <td>{item.attributes.created}</td>
                                <td>{item.attributes.modified}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <Link to={`/edit-cocktail/${item.id}`}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></Link>&nbsp;
                                    <a href="#"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );

        const loaderContainer = (
            <div>
                <h3>Loading ...</h3>
            </div>
        );

        return(
            <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <h1>List Cocktails</h1>
                { this.state.isLoading ? loaderContainer : cocktailsContent }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ListCocktailPage.propTypes = {
    getCocktails: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default connect(null, { getCocktails })(ListCocktailPage);
```

This is my `getCocktails()` function:

```
export function getCocktails() {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get('http://myapi.local/api/cocktails.json', { headers: headers }).then((response) => {
            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

Here a screenshot of my console. Also in the network tab I see he's requesting my api every second.

[image]

My opinion is that as soon as the api delivers the response, react thinks it needs to rerender the DOM. And then it creates a new request, receives a new response, and is falling into a loop.

How can I fix that? I'm too new into react, maybe I didn't understand the logic.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for downvoting. Why do people always downvote? My problem is explained well and I already have someone who answered and gave me a solution. Freakin' turds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call the `getCocktails` inside render function, in general you should never update state inside `render` function.

Move this function `getCocktails` inside `componentWillMount`

Explanation:

React will trigger render whenever the state is updated, so what you are doing is fetching data then update state from inside render function which result in another render -> then another fetch -> then another render so you need to move the fetch inside `componentWillMount` and remove it from render function

For more details about react lifecycle and component functions check this link

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: That easy. Haha. Thank you. Is anywhere a flow-cheatsheet? Are there other functions like `componentWillMount()`?

Comment: Yes `componentDidMount` and more functions, updated the answer with a good link that explains the lifecycle and the component functions and what they are doing